# How to combine two flutter projects using firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have designed a booking page using flutter and firebase. I used Cloud firestore to store all the  details of the users. Now i a need separate admin app to receive the data and modify it.how can i combine my firebase project with the admin app.

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple apps added to your Firebase project.

[image]

You can also use [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) to grant some of your users some additional claims which then you can use in scurity rules. In this way you can make some account have admin-like permissions.